# Do we really need an ending tag at all?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have removed the [specific scene tag recently](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/whats-the-point-of-the-specific-scene-tag) because that was not considered a good tag and used quite inconsistently and doesn't hold much value to it either.

Similarly I feel the [ending](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) tag is also not quite a good tag and used quite inconsistently. We might use [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) instead of it.

So why not get rid of it?

<sub>Open for counter arguments too</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure it's so wise to just call it out as a substitue for `plot-explanation`, since we don't exactly know yet how many of those questions are really plot explanation questions (unless you already checked and nearly all of them indeed are). Approaches like this are what lead to confusions on the other meta question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I didn't checked all, I fixed few but mostly removed it from ID.

Comment: Maybe not the most important function, but for me it's usable as an additional spoiler warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Keep the tag

The ending tag can be useful. Let's say a user isn't an expert on movies, but they've seen enough movies enough times to understand the basic plots/conclusions. That user need only click on the ending tag to look for questions they can answer and share their knowledge on. i.e. They see in the tagged questions something like "please explain the ending of this movie" and they can easily post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, let's get rid of it.

- [ending](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) is a **meta tag** - it wouldn't work as the *only* tag on a question, since it should be accompanied by a franchise tag - and therefore [should be burninated according to SE policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
- Nobody is going to use the [ending](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) tag to search for questions. One of the stated purposes of tags is to **increase searchability**, so that experts on a given topic can find questions on that topic to answer, but nobody is an expert on movie endings, nor is anybody going to think "hey, I'd like to answer some questions about *endings*" and go to look for questions with this tag.
- The tag **doesn't even have a clearly defined meaning**! The tag description says "The concluding/final part of a movie/tv show", but there's no objective way to define where this starts. Should this tag be used for any questions about the second half of a movie? Only for post-credits scenes? For the last 10 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes?

The confusion caused by this subjectivity is clear in the types of question asked with this tag. Some of them are specifically about the ending as imagined by the film-makers ...

- [How was Suspicion (1941) supposed to end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55220/how-was-suspicion-1941-supposed-to-end)
- [Why does Salt have two different endings?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44672/why-does-salt-have-two-different-endings)

... but others are simply about random scenes which happen to occur late in the film ...

- [How did the Doctor return to the present?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42157/how-did-the-doctor-return-to-the-present)
- [What is the significance of the Vichy Water scene at the end of Casablanca?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49327/what-is-the-significance-of-the-vichy-water-scene-at-the-end-of-casablanca)

... or even about aspects of the film which don't seem to be related specifically to the ending at all ...

- [What is Judy's and Nick's relationship?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49264/what-is-judys-and-nicks-relationship)
- [Won't Elena get old?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34388/wont-elena-get-old)

... not to mention poorly specified questions which say little more than "I didn't understand the ending of [film]; please can someone explain it to me?"

- [Can someone explain the ending of the movie "The House on Pine Street"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47355/can-someone-explain-the-ending-of-the-movie-the-house-on-pine-street)

Admittedly there aren't as many questions of this last type as one would think from browsing the *titles*, a huge number of which simply read "Ending of [film]" or "Explanation of the ending of [film]", which are almost as poorly specified as the "Please help me find this movie" titles.

---

**TL;DR: the tag serves no useful purpose, and it's found on a real dog's breakfast of different types of questions. Let's get rid of it.**

It may be possible to eliminate it simply by merging it into the [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) tag; however, I haven't checked whether *all* the [ending](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) questions are about plot explanation, which someone should certainly do before such a merge takes place.